# Why don't newly added files trigger my gulp-watch task?

Tags: gulp, gulp-imagemin, imagemin, gulp-watch

I have a gulp task which uses gulp-imagemin to compress images. When I add new files to this directory I'd like for this task to compress them as well. I read that [gulp.watch doesn't trigger on new files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391527/gulps-gulp-watch-not-triggered-for-new-or-deleted-files) and that I should try gulp-watch so I used it like so;

```
gulp.task('images', function() {
  watch({glob: './source/images/*'}, function (files) {
    return files
      .pipe(plumber())
      .pipe(imagemin({
        progressive: true,
        interlaced: true
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./www'));
  });
});
```

This works the same as gulp.watch on the first run, but when I add a new image to the directory nothing happens. If I overwrite an existing file however, it DOES run the task again, so it does behave differently.

The documentation on gulp-watch called this "Batch Mode" and said I could also run the task on a per-file basis, so I tried this way too;

```
gulp.task('images', function() {
  gulp.src('./source/images/*')
    .pipe(watch())
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(imagemin({
      progressive: true,
      interlaced: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www'));
});
```

But nothing changed. Why isn't adding files to my image directory triggering the task?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gulps gulp.watch not triggered for new or deleted files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391527/gulps-gulp-watch-not-triggered-for-new-or-deleted-files)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely such kind of questions are redirected to [gaze](https://github.com/shama/gaze) package and its internal processes, that runs complicated watching procedures on your OS. In this case you should pass `images/**/*` to glob option, so gaze will watch all (including new) files in images directory:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    watch({glob: 'images/**/*'}, function (files) {
      files.pipe(imagemin({
        progressive: true,
        interlaced: true
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./www'));
    });
});
```

But this fill not fix case, when you have empty images directory. If you want to watch them, pass `['images', 'images/**/*']` to glob, and it will watch directory, that initially empty.

P.s. also you dont need `gulp-plumber` in this case, because watch will rerun function, that uses imagemin every time, even when imagemin pops an error.

Comment: Thanks! I removed the "./" from source/images/ and it works now!

Answer (score 19):

Adding an extra argument `{cwd:'./'}` in `gulp.watch` worked for me:

```
gulp.watch('src/js/**/*.js',{cwd:'./'},['scripts']);
```

**2 things** to get this working:

**1** Avoid `./` in the file/folder patterns

**2** Ensure `./` in the value for `cwd`

Good Luck.

Ref:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/34346524/4742733